# Body inherits css properties even after stylesheet removal

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <script>
        function removeSheet(href) {
        var href;
        document.querySelector('link[href="'+href+'"]').outerHTML = '';
        }
        removeSheet( 'css/main.css');
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
body {
background: black;
}

h1 {
color:white;
}
```

The removeSheet function removes the stylesheet specified, and as expected, the h1 and all other elements lose all styling - but for some reason the body is still coloured black.

After inspecting the document in firebug, it shows that the stylesheet was properly removed from the page - but apparently the body is still inheriting styles from the css file.

Could anyone explain why the body keeps all its css properties, even if the stylesheet containing them is deleted ?

Comment: Your JS doesn't remove the CSS your document read from the link, just the link itself, the CSS is still in the browsers memory. Read about DOM (document object model) for example at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thanks! That explains a lot